# Add to cart only stock availabel quantity Magento Shop

Tags: magento2

I am working on a Magento 2.2 Shop. May be can some one help me with my Problem. I have for example in Stock only 5 Items for specific product. At the page of product the costumer at the moment can add to Cart a quantity more that I have in Stock (In Stock=5 Items, Client can for example 20 Items). How can I limit the buy quantity (add to cart quantity) for this product at the available Stock quantity.

Stock= 5 items => Add to cart no possibility more than 5 Items for this Product or to notify the customer that the desired quantity is not in stock

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Magento to manage stock for all products or even for only some of your products it will take care that a product can't be added in a higher quantity to the cart than you have on stock minus the configured minimum quantity that must be on stock.

For more details and screenshots of the exact settings check the documentation:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory.html